# transform polygon json coordinates into a data.frame

Tags: json, r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I want to transform a dataframe into another dataframe. If possible, in less commands, using `dplyr` or `tidyr` would be great.

In order to parse the coordinates list I used `library(rjson)`, this part is OK, but I cannot manipulate the list further to get my result.

Should you can avoid using any `for` statement would be great, but any solution is good as long as it solve the problem :)

Input:

```
df <- data.frame(code = c("12000", "89000"),
                 polygon = c("[[[11,12], [13,14], [15,16]], [[21, 22], [23,24], [25,26]]]",
                             "[[[81,82], [83,84], [85,86]]]"))
df

> df
   code                                                     polygon
1 12000 [[[11,12], [13,14], [15,16]], [[21, 22], [23,24], [25,26]]]
2 89000                               [[[81,82], [83,84], [85,86]]]
```

Input data description:

- column `code` contains postal code
- column `polygon` contains one or more polygons defined by their latitude-longitude pairs of points

Output wanted:

```
> wanted
       a lon lat id
1  12000  11  12  1
2  12000  13  14  1
3  12000  15  16  1
4  12000  21  22  2
5  12000  23  24  2
6  12000  25  26  2
7  89000  81  82  1
8  89000  83  84  1
9  89000  85  86  1
```

I want to plot the wanted data.frame using ggplot.

Comment: maybe you can finagle this to work: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyjson/vignettes/introduction-to-tidyjson.html

Comment: Couldn't find a way to use `tidyjson` with arrays/unnamed properties. How would you use `spread_values` in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`purrr`, `dplyr` and `jsonlite` solution:

```
df <- data.frame(code = c("12000", "89000"),
                 polygon = c("[[[11,12], [13,14], [15,16]], [[21, 22], [23,24], [25,26]]]",
                             "[[[81,82], [83,84], [85,86]]]"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

make_coords <- function(x) {
  fromJSON(x$polygon, simplifyMatrix=FALSE) %>% 
  map_df(~map_df(., ~setNames(as.data.frame(as.list(.)), c("lat", "lon"))), .id="id")
} 

group_by(df, a=code) %>% 
  do(make_coords(.)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(a, lat, lon, id)
## # A tibble: 9 x 4
##       a   lat   lon    id
##   <chr> <int> <int> <chr>
## 1 12000    11    12     1
## 2 12000    13    14     1
## 3 12000    15    16     1
## 4 12000    21    22     2
## 5 12000    23    24     2
## 6 12000    25    26     2
## 7 89000    81    82     1
## 8 89000    83    84     1
## 9 89000    85    86     1
```

This has the added benefit of validating the polygon data since your example ha[ds] invalid JSON (I had to edit out the final `]` in the initial example).

NOTES:

1. The `group_by` could be replaced by `dplyr::rowwise` or (with some other code changes) by `purrr::by_row`
2. The idiom is to iterate through each `code`, convert the JSON into a list of coordinates, iterate through that list and make a date frame out of each polygon, and assigning the positional ID to it.
3. The column names you want are assigned in three places: the initial `group_by` (to turn `code` into `a`), the innermost `map_df` (for `lat` & `lon`) and finally `id` which is auto-created by the outermost `map_df`.

`rowwise` version:

```
make_coords2 <- function(x) {
  fromJSON(x$polygon, simplifyMatrix=FALSE) %>% 
    map_df(~map_df(., ~setNames(as.data.frame(as.list(.)), c("lat", "lon"))), .id="id") %>% 
    mutate(a=x$a)
}

select(df, a=code, polygon) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do(make_coords2(.)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(a, lat, lon, id)
```

`by_row` version:

```
make_coords3 <- function(x) {
  fromJSON(x$polygon, simplifyMatrix=FALSE) %>% 
    map_df(~map_df(., ~setNames(as.data.frame(as.list(.)), c("lat", "lon"))), .id="id")
}

select(df, a=code, polygon) %>% 
  by_row(make_coords3, .collate="rows") %>% 
  select(a, lat, lon, id)
```

Comment: I've chosen this solution because I found it easier to use in my code. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't pretty, but some calls to `strsplit`, `gsub`, and `unnest` can do quite a bit:

- Splitting by `]],` allows us separate several polygons.
- We then spread those over separate rows.
- Create the `id` column can easily be done with `row_number` within each `code`
- Split again, on `],` to separate the point pairs.
- Put on seperate rows again.
- Remove all `[` and `]`.
- Separate on `,` to separate `lon` and `lat`.
- Put those in separate columns.

.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(polygon = strsplit(polygon, ']],')) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  group_by(code) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(),
         polygon = strsplit(polygon, '],')) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  mutate(polygon = gsub(']|\\[', '', polygon),
         polygon = strsplit(polygon, ','),
         lon = sapply(polygon, '[', 1),
         lat = sapply(polygon, '[', 2)) %>% 
  select(-polygon)
```

> ```
> Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
> Groups: code [2]
>
>    code    id   lon   lat
>   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>
> 1 12000     1    11    12
> 2 12000     1    13    14
> 3 12000     1    15    16
> 4 12000     2    21    22
> 5 12000     2    23    24
> 6 12000     2    25    26
> 7 89000     1    81    82
> 8 89000     1    83    84
> 9 89000     1    85    86
> ```

Comment: I didn't know that `unnest()` exists. But using it with `strsplit()` is not ok for me, I am not sure that `]],` is always a valid separator. I really like this solution and I'll look further to adapt it with my real data. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a closing bracket too much in df$polygon[2]. If that is removed, you could do the following:

```
require(jsonlite)
require(reshape2)
parse_json <- function(polygon, code){
  molten <- melt(fromJSON(polygon))
  lat <- molten[which(molten$Var3==1), "value"]
  lon <- molten[which(molten$Var3==2), "value"]
  id <- molten[which(molten$Var3==1), "Var1"]
  data.frame(code, lat, lon, id)
}

dat_raw <- mapply(parse_json, df$polygon, df$code, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
do.call(rbind, dat_raw)
```

Which gives you:

```
   code lat lon id
1 12000  11  12  1
2 12000  21  22  2
3 12000  13  14  1
4 12000  23  24  2
5 12000  15  16  1
6 12000  25  26  2
7 89000  81  82  1
8 89000  83  84  1
9 89000  85  86  1
```

Comment: Thank you @Floo0. I didn't use your solution because it uses `reshape2` and I've never understood how `melt()` works. But maybe this is a good occasion to start to explore the package.  Sorry! :)